# compatibility issue in a software with .exe & .bgi file

Tags: windows, bgi

I bought a book and received a CD along with it. The CD contains some programs. Each program has only 2 files; .exe file & an Interface file with .bgi extension. I'm not able to run .exe file. I tried it on different laptops with different OS. Tried troubleshooting compatibility  Windows 7, windows 8, Windows 10, windows xp. Tried everything I know. It didn't work. I complained to publisher. They say we have been selling the CD along with book from many years. Never received any such complaint. They sent a fresh CD. With new CD also I'm facing the same issue. Anyone expert in software engineering might know the reason?
Anyone willing to check the program himself? The software is uploaded on this link https://wsi.li/dl/8YwF7S3ipfEyKM2AT/a7438a
File size is 1.3MB

[In the attached pic Roy is executable file, EGAVGA is the Interface file of .bgi extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIpam.jpg)

[In the acknowledgement section of this paper, author has acknowledged that there are two files for each module. And read me file should be followed. However despite following his instructions, I am not able to resolve this issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHpFg.jpg)

Comment: It is 16-bit MS-Dos software from the 1980s, today with 64-bit operating systems everywhere it can only run in a DOS emulator.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to run it in DOS emulator. You are awesome.

Comment: Is there a away to modify the program? I mean the program is old and I want to add more parameters in the module. How can i do that?

Comment: https://edn.embarcadero.com/museum/antiquesoftware

Comment: I prepared some files using the .exe file in dosbox. what is the command to display the graphics of a file in dosbox?